Kubernetes Cronjob permissions issue
I have a Kubernetes CronJob for renewing vault tokens. And I am facing an error running this CronJob. This is the log from the pod:
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "vault-0" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:vault:vault-automation" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "vault"

I have found similar questions, checked answers but nothing have worked for me. I have created ServiceAccount, Role and RoleBinding. Here they are:
Cronjob:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: delete-namespace-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "00 23 * * *"  # Runs every day at 00:00 (midnight)
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: vault-automation
          containers:
          - name: delete-namespace
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
            args:
            - |
              kubectl exec vault-0 -n vault -- vault token renew -accessor llmc2pbuaJjksnKnkxgjx6dW;
              kubectl exec vault-0 -n vault -- vault token renew -accessor uqVZ6nFKycVWZQP49u82nnoW;
            env:
            - name: NAMESPACE
              value: "vault"
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 4

ServiceAccount:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
    name: vault-automation
    namespace: vault

Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: vault
  name: exec-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "exec"]

RoleBinding:
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: exec-rolebinding
  namespace: vault
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: vault-automation
  namespace: vault
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: exec-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io


cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "vault" <--- it explains with high level of details what permission for what type resource in what api group in what namespace it is missing. You don't need to find another answers or similar questions - just read carefully what it requires and allow it.

thanks a lot, resources: ["pods/exec", "pods"] solved the issue!
